# tvOS support for iBeacons

Tags: uikit, core-location, tvos

Does tvOS support all of the same iBeacon functionalities as iOS? My biggest concern is `CoreLocation` related functionality.

Comment: Are you trying to use tvOS as a beacon or a receiver? The functionality to act as a beacon is all there in CoreBluetooth (with a few hacks), but it would seem much harder to make a receiver.

Comment: Receiver. Hence the accepted answer and my reference to `CoreLocation`

Comment: File a radar and post the id.  I'd gladly file it as a dupe to get it some attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all of the same functionality is supported, [CoreLocation Changes for Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/CoreLocation.html).

```
Removed CLBeacon
Removed CLBeacon.accuracy
Removed CLBeacon.major
Removed CLBeacon.minor
Removed CLBeacon.proximity
Removed CLBeacon.proximityUUID
Removed CLBeacon.rssi
Removed CLBeaconRegion
Removed -[CLBeaconRegion initWithProximityUUID:identifier:]
Removed -[CLBeaconRegion initWithProximityUUID:major:identifier:]
Removed -[CLBeaconRegion initWithProximityUUID:major:minor:identifier:]
Removed CLBeaconRegion.major
Removed CLBeaconRegion.minor
Removed CLBeaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay
Removed -[CLBeaconRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:]
Removed CLBeaconRegion.proximityUUID
```

For a complete list of iOS API's that are available for tvOS refer to: [iOS 9.0 to tvOS 9.0 API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/index.html)